# Https in IIS is not working with non www domain

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, iis, https

I am developing an ASP Core web application and deploy it to IIS server V10. I bought a ssl certificate from digicert with only a domain name. For example, `example.com`. It works just fine when I access to it `example.com`. But when I try `https://www.example.com`, there's a security alert about my certificate because it does not match.
I am new to iis server and asp core. I really have no idea about it.
Is there any misconfiguration or should I buy another domain with www?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Talk to DigiCert, as they should have helped you getting a certificate that covers both non-www and www at least. There is nothing you can do on IIS or ASP.NET Core. When in doubt, run a report to learn more, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: I'll look for it. Thanks.

Comment: Did you get any error messages? Regardless of whether there is www, they should all work normally.

Comment: @samwu no, that's not true. The common name and DNS names set in the certificate matters, and nothing is guaranteed work normally when different CAs sell/generate certificates differently (some does charge more if you want to cover both www and non-www).